# Upper Bound Of Product Of $\dfrac{p_i}{p_i -1}$

Tags: number-theory

I am trying to prove the following:
$ \prod_{i=1}^{m}\dfrac{p_i}{p_i-1} = O(\mbox{log } m) = O (m^\epsilon) $, where $p_i$ denotes the $i$-th prime.

What I have tried is the following:
$ \prod_{i=1}^{m}\dfrac{p_i}{p_i-1} \leq \left(\dfrac{2}{2-1}\right)^m = 2^m$.  So I need to to prove

$2^m \leq c \log (m)$ $\Rightarrow$ $2 \leq c^{\frac{1}{m}} (\log m)^\frac{1}{m}$. Now
$c^\frac{1}{m} \rightarrow 1$ as $m \rightarrow \infty $, so can we say that $2 \leq (\log m)^\frac{1}{m}$  as  $m \rightarrow \infty $ ?

Please suggest me any other way to do this...Thanks.

Comment: This is Mertens's third theorem.

Comment: I saw the Merten's 3rd theorem from wikipedia. It is considering the product over primes upto n. And here in the question, I need to take the product over first n primes (like this). How can I relate?

Comment: you have that $\prod_{p\leq n}\frac p{p-1}=O(\log(n))$ right? From there you can use the prime number theorem to get the result you want. Actually there's a result by Chebyschev that says that $\frac{an}{\log(n)}<\pi(n)<\frac{bn}{\log(n)}$ for some constants $a,b$ which is sufficient. That's way easier to prove than the full prime number theorem, see here for example https://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/lg5/Chebyshev.pdf.